# Error with one-to-many relationship in MVC Entity Framework 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I get the following error when I run up my code-first MVC app and try and visit either the DeveloperAccountModel details page or another view that loads a parent object and a collection of DeveloperAccountModel: **The navigation property 'Redirects' is not a declared property on type 'DeveloperAccountModel'**. At this point, I am not accessing the property (which does exist!) just attempting to load the DeveloperAccountModel.

```
 [Table("sitedata")]
public class DeveloperAccountModel
{
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$")]
    [Display(Name = "User id")]
    [Key]
    [Column("_rowid")]
    public long RowId { get; internal set; }

    // Other properties removed

    [Display(Name = "Redirects")]
    [NotMapped]
    [InverseProperty("DeveloperAccount")]
    public List<SiteRedirectModel> Redirects { get; internal set; }
}
```

And then the dependent model

```
[Table("siteredirects")]
public partial class SiteRedirectModel
{
    [Key]
    [Column("_rowid")]
    [Display(Name = "RowId")]
    public int RowId { get; internal set; }

    [Column("_siteid")]
    [Display(Name = "Developer account id")]
    public long DeveloperAccountModelId { get; internal set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [ForeignKey("DeveloperAccountModelId")]
    public virtual DeveloperAccountModel DeveloperAccount { get; internal set; }
}
```

I have tried so many variations of the various tutorials and samples including other times where this or a similar error occurs but I am not seeing something really simple. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, remove the `[NotMapped]` attribute from both properties. So your properties definition should look like:

```
// In SiteRedirectModel
[ForeignKey("DeveloperAccountModelId")]
public virtual DeveloperAccountModel DeveloperAccount { get; internal set; }




// In DeveloperAccountModel
[Display(Name = "Redirects")]
[InverseProperty("DeveloperAccount")]
public List<SiteRedirectModel> Redirects { get; internal set; }
```

Comment: This has removed the error, thanks so much. I am not getting any data in the view though, I have used this @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Redirects.FirstOrDefault().RowId) is this correct and do I need to do anything to make sure the Redirects are loaded? (That's why I removed the virtual to make it eager loaded). Thanks

Comment: Scratch that! I added .Include() in the controller and it all works lovely.

Comment: @Lukos Add the `virtual` keyword. Or use `Include`